# TWIG вывод значения массива, по ключу из переменной

Tags: php, twig

Существует многоуровневый массив

```
  $params = [
      'param1' => [
          'param1_1' => [
              'param1_1_1' => 'test'             
           ]
       ]
  ];
```

И есть переменная `$key = 'param1.param1_1.param1_1_1';`

Если обращаться на прямую в `TWIG` `{{ params.param1.param1_1.param1_1_1 }}`
То соответственно на экран выйдет результат, а как это сделать если путь до значения храниться в переменной?

что-то типа `{{ params.key }}` - где `key`, переменная описанная выше.

Comment: @The art of being alive возможно есть способ реализовать это через создание функции TWIG, и кто-то это сделал, а это уже PHP

Answer (score 0):

Вам подойдет функция attribute

```
attribute(params, key)
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает если указывать вложенные значения по типу `param1.param1_1.param1_1_1` выводит только значения первого уровня